# How remove an element in all documents of an index in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have list of documents in an index of Elasticsearch like below:

```
...
{
  "_index" : "index-name",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "table1c7151240c583e60c8e2cbad351",
  "_score" : 0.28322574,
  "_source" : {
    ...
    "table.tag" : {
      "datasources_keys" : [...],
      "tags" : [
        "6e7358e2bfc84c34af32a01f6d19e9b2",
        "ab450ae5c1734fb0aad5fed052b42023",
        "f725e3100bba4b5eb8a5199a2b3e62fc"
      ]
    }
  }
},
...
```

I wanna delete an element in all documents.. for example should remove a specified `tag_id` in `tags` like `"6e7358e2bfc84c34af32a01f6d19e9b2"` .. how should I write a script for that? Is there other way in elasticsearch?

I'm using this script.. but it doesnt work!!

```
POST index-name/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match":{
      "table.tag.tags": "6e7358e2bfc84c34af32a01f6d19e9b2"
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source['table.tag']['tags'] -= 6e7358e2bfc84c34af32a01f6d19e9b2",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

Comment: For starters, I think your match query on `index.tag.tags` doesn't match anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more concise way with implicit list iterations and if conditions (+ it's a one-liner ):

```
POST index-name/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "table.tag.tags": "6e7358e2bfc84c34af32a01f6d19e9b2"
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless"
    "source": "ctx._source['table.tag']['tags'].removeIf(tag -> tag == params.tag);",
    "params": {
      "tag": "6e7358e2bfc84c34af32a01f6d19e9b2"
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can add your second condition like this:

```
ctx._source['table.tag']['tags'].removeIf(tag -> tag == params.tag);
if (ctx._source['table.tag']['tags'].size() == 0) {
    ctx._source['table.tag'].remove('tags');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..Your solution is working..
How if I use another if condition in that script? I wanna check size of tags after removing.. if there is not more tags, remove whole inventory.tag : `if(ctx._(source['inventory.tag']['tags'].count)==0){             ctx._source['inventory.tag'].remove(i);}`
 is it ok? how should I handle it?

Comment: actually, I had not used your solution `(painless)`.. but now, I've been searching about `painless`.. I found out about its benefits rather than using `for loop`.. so, I've updated my codes and now I'm using your solution! Thanks for your follow-up :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try below script:

```json
POST index-name/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "table.tag.tags": "6e7358e2bfc84c34af32a01f6d19e9b2"
    }
  },
 "script": {
    "source": """
    for (int i = 0; i < ctx._source['table.tag']['tags'].length; i++)
    {
      if(ctx._source['table.tag']['tags'][i]=='6e7358e2bfc84c34af32a01f6d19e9b2')
      {
            ctx._source['table.tag']['tags'].remove(i);
      }
    }"""
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot.. that's work..
How if I should use another `if condition` in that script? I wanna use count in that like below:
`if(ctx._(source['inventory.tag']['tags'].count)==0)
      {
            ctx._source['inventory.tag'].remove(i);
      }`
is it ok? how should I handle it?

Comment: @ShokouhDareshiri you need to use length instead of count for total number of elements. Yes, you can add another if condition as well